# What gets repaired when I repair "All Items"?

Tags: diablo-iii

Vendors in Diablo III have two options for repairing, *Equipped* and *All Items*. The *All Items* option repairs equipped items and items in the player's inventory, but does it also repair items in the player's stash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not repair items stored in the stash.

Comment: Would be nice if that option were available from the AH. Hate having to join a game, pluck the items from my stash, repair them, then put them back.

Comment: @Tater596 Why are you dumping stuff into the stash before you repair it? :)

Comment: @fbueckert If you have never stashed items without remembering to repair them I do not think you have played this game very much...

Comment: @Alderath I think the correct response is that he plays to much if always thinks to do that.